# Is it possible to run an incognito with normal Chrome browser instance with Protractor?

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I need to run test in two browsers with the same view but logged with different users. As the server is changing the cookie and logging out the first user because of the shared cookie between multiple windows in Chrome I cannot run the test. So, I wonder if it is possible to run a Chrome normal instance and an incognito one simultaneously.

Another option is to run a Chrome and a Firefox instance but I need to control what to do with each browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two browsers. Run a script to find out which browser you are in and then have different users to log based on that.
First, get the browser, here is a script for that:

```
browser.getCapabilities()
.then(function(s) {

var platform = s.caps_.platform,
    browserName = s.caps_.browserName,
    browserVersion = s.caps_.version,
    shortVersion = browserVersion.split('.')[0],
    ie = /i.*explore/.test(browserName),
    ff = /firefox/.test(browserName),
    ch = /chrome/.test(browserName),
    sa = /safari/.test(browserName),
    shortName;

if (ie) {
    shortName = 'ie';
} else if (ff) {
    shortName = 'ff';
} else if (ch) {
    shortName = 'ch';
} else if (sa) {
    shortName = 'sa';
} else {
    throw new Exception('Unsupported browser: '+ browserName);
}

// Returns one of these: ['ch', 'ff', 'sa', 'ie']
browser.getShortBrowserName = function() {
    return shortName;
};

// Returns one of these: ['ch33', 'ff27', 'sa7', 'ie11', 'ie10', 'ie9']
browser.getShortNameVersionAll = function() {
    return shortName + shortVersion;
};

// Returns one of these: ['ch', 'ff', 'sa', 'ie11', 'ie10', 'ie9']
browser.getShortNameVersion = function() {
    if (ie) {
        return shortName + shortVersion;
    } else {
        return shortName;
    }
};

// Return if current browser is IE, optionally specifying if it is a particular IE version
browser.isIE = function(ver) {
    if (!ver) {
        return ie;
    } else {
        return ie && ver.toString() === shortVersion;
    }
};

browser.isSafari = function() {
    return sa;
};

browser.isFirefox = function() {
    return ff;
};

// Return if current browser is Chrome, optionally specifying if it is a particular Chrome version
browser.isChrome = function(ver) {
    if (!ver) {
        return ch;
    } else {
        return ch && ver.toString() === shortVersion;
    }
};
```

then you need a function to know which user to log in:

```
global.getUserAndPassword = function getUser() {

var rv_user = process.env.PROTRACTOR_USER;

if (browser.isFireFox() && typeof process.env.PROTRACTOR_USER_2 !== 'undefined') {
  rv_user = process.env.PROTRACTOR_USER_2;
}

return [rv_user, process.env.PROTRACTOR_PASSWORD];
```

};

and then a login function:

```
global.loginFn = function loginFn() {
 var user_and_pass = getUserAndPassword();

 username.sendKeys(user_and_pass[0]);
 password.sendKeys(user_and_pass[1]);
 login.click();
};
```